# This C code keeps giving me a segmentation fault in codeblocks

Tags: c, string, split, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

This a problem I keep trying to fix, but fail. Why do you think it is so?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

        int main(void)
    {
        char str[500];
        sprintf(str, "int cube = %i;", 29);
        char *ptr;
        strtok_r (str, "=", &ptr);
        printf ("'%s'  '%s'\n\n", str, ptr);
        char temp[500];
        sprintf(temp, "%s", ptr);
        int conditional = atoi(temp);
        puts(conditional);
        return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Use return value of `strtok_r`.

Comment: `puts(conditional);` --> `printf("%d\n", conditional);`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
puts(conditional);
```

The `puts` function expect a `char *` which points to a string.  You're passing in an `int` instead.  This is undefined behavior.

The value of that `int` is being interpreted as a pointer which probably doesn't point to a valid memory location, causing the crash.

If you want to print an `int`, use `printf` instead with the `%d` format specifier.

```
printf("%d\n", conditional);
```